# Comparing Structure of Nested Collections

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-test-runner

When using Microsoft Visual Studio's built-in unit testing framework, how do I compare two collections that contain nested collections for equality when child collections are considered equal if their contents are equal?

In the below example, `AreEquals` fails because each list contains a different nested list instance.

```
var a = new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "a" } };
var b = new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "a" } };

CollectionAssert.AreEqual(a, b);
```

I'm looking for an assertion that returns true when comparing `a` and `b` because the nested collections match in structure/contents even though they are not the same list instance.

Am I missing an easy way to do this? Writing an `IEqualityComparer<T>` is an option but I'm hoping there's a simple route.... :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool AreEqual(List<List<string>> la, List<List<string>> lb)
{   
    if(la == null || lb == null) return false;
    if(la.Count() != lb.Count()) return false;
    for(int i; i ++; i < la.Count()) 
    {
       if(la[i].Count() != lb[i].Count()) return false;
       for(int j; j ++; j < la[i].Count()) 
       {
           if(la[i][j] != lb[i][j]) return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if it would tell you what the difference is and where in the two lists the difference is found. You get both features for free using StatePrinter

Comment: @CarloV.Dango Stated question is test if equal.   Why comment to me?  The OP will be able to see your answer.